# Hay alguna manera de filtrar palabras?

Tags: java

mi programa coge las palabras repetidas de un texto y te las muestra.Hasta ahí todo bien.El problema surge a la hora de introducir un texto relativamente extenso  se guardan como palabras clave las preposiciones,determinantes.etc y, (que lo dudo mucho) habría alguna manera de filtrarlos que no sea poniendo todas las preposiciones,adjetivos,determinantes del lenguaje en un `if` enorme?

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String texto = txt.getText();
    String impresion = "Palabras clave: ";
    String anadir = "";
    String anadir1 = "";
    ArrayList<String> palabras = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<String> palabrasclave = new ArrayList();
    int n = 0;
    int longitudtexto = texto.length() - 1;

    if (texto.charAt(longitudtexto) != '.' || texto.charAt(longitudtexto) != ' ' || texto.charAt(longitudtexto) != ',') {
        texto += ".";
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < texto.length(); x++) {
        if (texto.charAt(x) == ' ' || texto.charAt(x) == '.' || texto.charAt(x) == ',') {
            palabras.add(anadir);
            anadir = "";
        } else {
            anadir += texto.charAt(x);
        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < palabras.size(); i++) {

        String palabraencuestion = palabras.get(i);

        for (int y = 0; y < palabras.size(); y++) {

            if (palabrasclave.contains(palabraencuestion)) {
                contiene = true;
            } else {
                contiene = false;
            }
            String palabra = palabras.get(y);

            if (palabraencuestion.equals(palabra) && i != y && contiene == false) {

                palabrasclave.add(palabraencuestion);

            }
        }
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < palabrasclave.size(); y++) {

        anadir1 += palabrasclave.get(y);
        if (y != 0 || y != palabrasclave.size()) {
            anadir1 += " - ";
        }
    }

    lbl.setText("Las palabras clave son: " + anadir1);
}
```

Comment: Podrias agregar todas esas palabras a una lista, y  fijarte si la palabra que estas verificando en la condicion del if existe en la lista con lista.contains(palabra)

Comment: De todas formas subi tu codigo y se te va a poder ayudar mucho mejor y mas precisamente

Comment: Pon ejemplo de entrada y ejemplo de salida deseada así sabremos si hay caracteres especiales o algún indicio de la heurística a seguir para realizar la tarea eficientemente, seguramente con streams logras lo que necesitas en un dos por tres

Comment: Entrada : "Pepe luis fué un gran escritor.Pepe luis fué un gran caballero "      Salida deseada : " Pepe - luis  "  Salida : "Pepe - luis - fué - un"